# What is mean when it raises a PicklingError?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle

Hy there!
I'm new on python 3. 
I'm using the pvmomi module to get a dict of vm's from my server. When i try to  run my file, with multiprocessing, i get the following Error:

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup vim.VirtualMachine on pyVmomi.VmomiSupport failed

What does this mean?

Here is a part of my code:

```
def login(vm):
    #do something

if __name__=='__main__':
    cpu = mp.cpu_count()
    workers = mp.Pool(cpu)
    workers.map(login,range(1))
    for vm in vmDict:
        login(vm)
```

My biggest problem comes from the for loop. I need this loop to do the jobs for every dictitem but only one pool worker do the job. Now i have configured my code to this below and it raises the PicklingError. 
Thanks for help. It drives me crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stdlib pickle (.py) module imports the builtin C-coded _pickle module.  The pickle module can serialize most Python objects and is used to transport Python objects between processes.  In particular, pickle is used by multiprocessing (and perhaps by pyvmomi).  User-defined classes sometimes define special methods (**reduce** and **reducex**, I believe) to help the pickle and unpickle processes.

The exception message says that an attribute lookup failed.  Perhaps the pyVmomi object is not properly configured to be pickled.  You might check to module doc to see if it says anything about pickle support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your right. and the pyVmomi Object is not configured for that. Do you know another way to use multiprocessing for these Objekts? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!